# Consolidate duplicate rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame where one column is species' names, and the second column is abundance values.  Due to the sampling procedure, some species appear more than once (i.e., there is more than one row with Species X in it).  I would like to consolidate those entries and sum their abundances.

For example, given this data frame:

```
set.seed(6)
df=data.frame(
  x=c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp3","sp4","sp2","sp3"),
  y=rpois(7,2)); df
```

which produces:

```
    x y
1 sp1 2
2 sp2 4
3 sp3 1
4 sp3 1
5 sp4 3
6 sp2 5
7 sp3 5
```

I would like to instead produce:

```
    x y
1 sp1 2    
2 sp2 9     (5+4)
3 sp3 7     (5+1+1)
5 sp4 3
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This works:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,"x",numcolwise(sum))
```

in words: (1) split the data frame `df` by the `"x"` column; (2) for each chunk, take the sum of each numeric-valued column; (3) stick the results back into a single data frame. (`dd` in `ddply` stands for "take a **d** ata frame as input, return a **d** ata frame")

Another, possibly clearer, approach:

```
aggregate(y~x,data=df,FUN=sum)
```

See [quick/elegant way to construct mean/variance summary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449198/quick-elegant-way-to-construct-mean-variance-summary-table) for a related (slightly more complex) question.

Comment: D'oh!  How did this textbook application of ddply slip past me...Thanks Ben!

Comment: +1 for application of numcolwise and sum. I was mucking about with transform and mutate trying to get exactly this to work.

Comment: AFAIK, "aggregate(y~x+z,data=df,FUN=sum)" could be used to preserve an *additional* column (here "z"), should there be the need (was the need in my case). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 31):

Simple as `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(df['y'], by=df['x'], sum)
```

Answer (score 14):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(y = sum(y))
```

Answer (score 9):

A `data.table` solution for time and memory efficiency

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
# which columns are numeric 
numeric_cols <- which(sapply(DT, is.numeric))
DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = x, .SDcols = numeric_cols]
```

Or, in your case, given that you know that there is only the 1 column `y` you wish to sum over

```
DT[, list(y=sum(y)),by=x]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
> tapply(df$y, df$x, sum)
sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 
  2   9   7   3
```

if it has to be a `data.frame` Ben's answer works great. or you can coerce the tapply output.

```
out <- tapply(df$y, df$x, sum)
>     data.frame(x=names(out), y=out, row.names=NULL)
    x y
1 sp1 2
2 sp2 9
3 sp3 7
4 sp4 3
```

Answer (score 2):

A MWE to verify whether a formula to respect a second variable (i.e., here "Z" and in addition to "X", would actually work:

```
example = data.frame(X=c("x"),Z=c("a"),Y=c(1), stringsAsFactors=F)
newrow = c("y","b",1)
example <- rbind(example, newrow)
newrow = c("z","a",0.5)
example <- rbind(example, newrow)
newrow = c("x","b",1)
example <- rbind(example, newrow)
newrow = c("x","b",2)
example <- rbind(example, newrow)
newrow = c("y","b",10)
example <- rbind(example, newrow)
example$X = as.factor(example$X)
example$Z = as.factor(example$Z)
example$Y = as.numeric(example$Y)
example_agg <- aggregate(Y~X+Z,data=example,FUN=sum)
```