# How can I write the code to generate a summarized table in R?

Tags: r

Here I would like to summary the data by min, max, and mean.

```
set.seed(55775)
x <- round(runif(150000,1,1000),2)
g <- sample(LETTERS[1:4],150000,replace=T)
```

I know tapply can do the summary, `tapply(x,g,summary)`, and it will give the same answer as the following table, but I don't know how to generate this neat table instead of using tapply...

```
g   MIN    MAX     MEAN
A  1.06  999.94  500.5395
B  1.01  999.95  501.6863
C  1.01  999.99  503.8504
D  1.05  999.97  500.5327
```

Comment: Please [search SO and I am sure you will find nice answers you can adapt to your own data](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+summary+statistics+per+group). [This is also a good starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega). Cheers.

Comment: [Here's another.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449198/quick-elegant-way-to-construct-mean-variance-summary-table)

Answer (score 3):

Since `tapply` returns a `list` in this case, you can just use `do.call(rbind, ...)` and extract the columns you are interested in:

```
do.call(rbind, tapply(x, g, summary))[, c("Min.", "Max.", "Mean")]
#   Min.   Max.  Mean
# A 1.06  999.9 500.5
# B 1.01 1000.0 501.7
# C 1.01 1000.0 503.9
# D 1.05 1000.0 500.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there...

```
> t1 <- tapply(x, g, summary)
### sapply is basically loop over 4x items in list `t1` to extract values
### then t() to transpose to fit your example
> t2 <- t( sapply(1:nrow(t1), function (i) t1[[i]][c("Min.", "Max.", "Mean")]) )
### rename per your example:
> rownames(t2) <-  names(t1)
> colnames(t2) <- c(" MIN", " MAX", " MEAN")
```

giving:

```
> t2
   MIN    MAX  MEAN
A 1.06  999.9 500.5
B 1.01 1000.0 501.7
C 1.01 1000.0 503.9
D 1.05 1000.0 500.5
```

See `?format` if you want to fine-tune the presentation any further.